# why we use __icontains in django

Tags: contains

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        song_results = Song.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            albums = albums.filter(
                Q(album_title__icontains=query) |
                Q(artist__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            song_results = song_results.filter(
                Q(song_title__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            return render(request, 'music/index.html', {
                'albums': albums,
                'songs': song_results,
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums}
```

Comment: Consider formatting the code and writing a description of the problem you are having.